# I want to output characters but output Chinese information. What's wrong?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I want to output characters but output Chinese information. What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int n;
        char c;
        int sum = 1; /* 当前的和   */
        int t;       /* 合理的和   */
        int col = 1; /* 当前的星数 */
        scanf_s("%d %c", &n, &c);
        while (sum <= n) {
            t = sum;
            col += 2;
            sum += col * 2;
        }
        col -= 2;    /* 合理的星数 */
    
        int b = 0;
        int row = col;   /* 待打印的行数 */
        int flag = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
            for (int z = 0; z < b; ++z) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
                printf("%c", c);
            }
            if (col != 1 && flag) {
                col -= 2;
                ++b;
            }
            else if (col = 1 || !flag) {
                col += 2;
                --b;
                flag = 0;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%d\n", n - t);
        return 0;

}
```

[image]

[image: enter image description heenter code herere]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't post images of text. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste the text *as text*, as well as improving the question itself (for example to actually *ask* a question).

Comment: `scanf_s("%d %c", &n, &c);`  is an **incorrect** use of `scanf_s`

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `#include <wchar.h>`, `wchar_t`, `wprintf` and `wscanf_s`. And for Windows, `wmain` instead of `main`.

Comment: What do you expect, and what do you get? Please be more specific, I do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

After modifying the program, the program can now run correctly.

Modification 1:

```
scanf_s("%d %c", &n, &c, 2);
```

Modification 2:

```
else if (col == 1 || !flag) {
```